# List subscribed datasets in AWS Marketplace using a Python code

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-marketplace, aws-data-exchange

i'm trying to list the datasets that i subscribed from AWS market place but im not able to do so it's just returning empty set.

```
import boto3
import os

# Set AWS credentials as environment variables
os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = '*******************'
os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] = '************************'
os.environ['AWS_REGION'] = 'us-west-1'

# Create a client for the AWS Marketplace Commerce Analytics Service API
client = boto3.client('dataexchange',
                      region_name='us-west-2')

#print(dir(client))


# Use the search_products operation to retrieve a list of products
response = client.list_data_sets(
    #MaxResults=123,
    #NextToken='string',
    Origin='ENTITLED'
)

# Extract the product names from the response and print them to the console

products = response['DataSets']
#for product in products:
print(products)
```

Comment: Does your IAM role have the permission `arn:aws:quicksight:region:aws-account-id:dataset/*` ?

Comment: How did you Subscribe to the data set? Is it showing as Subscribed when you view the AWS Data Exchange console?

Comment: yes my IAM has the role permissions  and its showing the subscribed data sets under my subscription in AWS data exchnage console